# Chrome is not rendering source map URL correctly

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

In my `pdfmake.min.js` file, available on the URL at `/client/pdf/pdfmake.min.js`, on the last line I have

```
//# sourceMappingURL=pdfmake.min.js.map
```

which respects the [source map rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map) and according to URL rules it should point to `/client/pdf/pdfmake.min.js.map` (as there is no `/` in the pointer)

But Chrome gives warning

> DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: https://autocosts.work/pdfmake.min.js.map
>   18:37:05.952

It seems it is a bug, as Chrome is searching for the file at the root of the URL and not on the same directory of the pointing file.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Chrome are you seeing this in?

I can't reproduce this problem on a [simple test page](https://webdbg.com/test/script/). Does your page have anything unusual about it (e.g. a `base` element)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. As you can see at the last line of [this js file](https://autocosts.info/client/pdf/pdfmake.min.js) at `/client/pdf/pdfmake.min.js` it is written `//# sourceMappingURL=pdfmake.min.js.map` but Chrome is trying to find the map on the root `/pdfmake.min.js`. My version is 69.0.3497.81

Comment: Chrome 69 is fairly outdated at this point; do you see the same problem with my test page?